# using get_context_data() method to retrieve a list of dependant objects within DetailView Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I am creating a simple car dealership application in Django 3 whereby when goes to a detail page of a category it should list all cars that belong in that category , so in my case car objects are dependent objects of their respective category . I have tried to implement this using get_context_data() method and referencing the two respective models within the DetailView here is my code

models.py category

```
from django.db import models

from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

models.py cars

```
from django.db import models

from django.urls import reverse

from categories.models import Category

# Create your models here.


class Car(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/cars/')
    make = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=30)
    model = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=30)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    transmission = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=30)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('car_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views categories

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from .models import Category
from cars.models import Car
# Create your views here.


class CategoryList(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category_list.html'


class CategoryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'category_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs)
        context['category_cars'] = Car.objects.filter(
            category=self.request.name)
        return context
```

urls categories

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import CategoryList, CategoryDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('categories/', CategoryList.as_view(), name='categories'),
    path('categories/<int:pk>/', CategoryDetailView.as_view(), name='category_detail')
]
```

so using my above implementation results into an error

[image]

any suggestions so as to achieve my desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are transferred through  **`kwargs`** also your parameter name is **`pk`** and not `name`

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(CategoryDetailView, self).get_context_data(
        *args, **kwargs)
    context['category_cars'] = Car.objects.filter(
        category=context['object']
    )
    return context
```

But you actually don't need to do this as Category objects have access to their [related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) Car objects ( **`car_set`**):

```
{% for car in object.car_set.all %}
   {{car.make}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried the car_set solution you provided but got this error instead       ``` TypeError at /categories/7/
'RelatedManager' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/7/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'RelatedManager' object is not iterable ```

Comment: even your first solution failed with a keyerror     like this      ```   KeyError at /categories/7/
'pk'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/7/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'pk'   ```

Comment: could you help out with this question as well     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429442/using-form-valid-method-to-acess-objects-from-requests-made-in-django